# How do i screenshot chrome browser when my tests fail and before the chrome browser closes (@After)

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I have ran this code and the screenshot gets captured after the chrome browser closes (@After)
If i comment out CloseBrowser(); the screenshot gets captured but the chromebrowser stay open. 
I want the screenshot to capture on a failed test then close the browser.

in summary
The screenshot currently captures after the browser closes, which is just a blank .png
I want the screenshot to capture when a test fails just before the browser closes

Thanks

```
public class TestClass extends classHelper//has BrowserSetup(); and CloseBrowser(); {

 @Rule
 public ScreenshotTestRule my = new ScreenshotTestRule(); 

 @Before
 public void BeforeTest()
 {
      BrowserSetup();// launches chromedriver browser
 }

 @Test
 public void ViewAssetPage() 
 {
     //My test code here//And want to take screenshot on failure
 }

 @After
 public void AfterTest() throws InterruptedException
 {
      CloseBrowser();//closes the browser after test passes or fails
 }
}

class ScreenshotTestRule implements MethodRule {
    public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final FrameworkMethod frameworkMethod, final Object o) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    statement.evaluate();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    captureScreenshot(frameworkMethod.getName());
                    throw t; // rethrow to allow the failure to be reported to JUnit
                }
            }
            public void captureScreenshot(String fileName) {
                try {
                    new File("target/surefire-reports/").mkdirs(); // Insure directory is there
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("target/surefire-reports/screenshot-" + fileName + ".png");
                    out.write(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // No need to crash the tests if the screenshot fails
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found a way to implement the screenshots. I have created a method that will take a screenshot. I have put a try and catch around my test code and catch an exception and calling the method to take a screenshot.

```
       public class TestClass extends classHelper//has BrowserSetup(); and CloseBrowser(); {`

     @Rule
     public ScreenshotTestRule my = new ScreenshotTestRule(); 

     @Before
     public void BeforeTest()
     {
          BrowserSetup();// launches chromedriver browser
     }

     @Test
     public void ViewAssetPage() 
     {
       try
      {
        //My test code here//And want to take screenshot on failure
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          //print e
          takeScreenShot();
      }
     }

     @After
     public void AfterTest() throws InterruptedException
     {
          CloseBrowser();//closes the browser after test passes or fails
     }
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
void takeScreenShot()
        {
            try
            {
                int num = 0;
                String fileName = "SS"+NAME.getMethodName()+".png";//name of file/s you wish to create
                String dir = "src/test/screenshot";//directory where screenshots live

                new File(dir).mkdirs();//makes new directory if does not exist
                File myFile = new File(dir,fileName);//creates file in a directory n specified name

                while (myFile.exists())//if file name exists increment name with +1
                {
                   fileName = "SS"+NAME.getMethodName()+(num++)+".png";
                   myFile = new File(dir,fileName);
                }

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(myFile);//creates an output for the created file
                out.write(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));//Takes screenshot and writes the screenshot data to the created file
                //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("target/surefire-reports/" + fileName);
                out.close();//closes the outputstream for the file
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // No need to crash the tests if the screenshot fails
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement TestNG Listeners to execute code before a test or after a test
Or when a test fails or succeeded etc.

Implement it like below and put your screenshot in the method i showed

```
public class Listeners implements ITestListener {

Methods…
And put the screenshot code inside the method below:

@Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        code for screenshot
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/383

The ordering for rule execution has changed with new 'TestRule'